# Select most top level element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a html code :

```
<div class="body">
    <p></p>
    <div class="select">
        <p class="p1"></p>
        <div class="select"></div>
        <p class="p2"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select `div` element with class `select`. There are two element of this type which I want the parent one. How can I do that? Pay attention that the above code is just an example and the code can become complex arbitrarily.

Two `div` elements with same class may not be direct child and parent of each other and I want to do this by `css-selectors` if possible.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think that is a duplicate - if anything the is there a [parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) question would be more of a duplicate OP is looking for root of class not first of class

Answer (score -1):

Style the `.select` and then overwrite those styles in `.select .select`:

```css
.select {
  /* top level select element */
  color: red;
}

.select .select {
  /* reset styles in nested select element */
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <p>Text</p>
    <div class="select">
        <p class="p1">Top Level Select</p>
        <div class="select">Nested Select</div>
        <p class="p2">Top Level Select</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="p1">Text</p>
        <div class="select">Top Level Select</div>
        <p class="p2">Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```